# Is Chochmas Ha'Yad a Jewish thing?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

Is Chochmas Ha'Yad (which I think is the ability/technique of being able to look at a person's palm and be able to figure out about the person through the lines on his palm) a concept that is specific to Judiasm or is it something that many religions/groups/communities believe in?

Comment: As phrased this is probably off topic, but I'll just dupe it anyway since you may find that info helpful

Comment: @DoubleAA. That info actuall was very informative and helpful. Thank you. But I'm specifically asking if it's a chochma specific to Jewish tradition or is it a chochma like every secular chochma (astrology, medicine etc) which is shared (at its sources) by all religions, communities and traditions.

Comment: @MarkA. (re your comment), then your question is about not Judaism but other religions, communities, and traditions, and you should ask their adherents, members, and recipients, respectively.